# Query to determine whether more than one element has the same value for a property?

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq, .net-4.0

I am trying to write a LINQ query which will return true if there are multiple objects which have a property with the same value.

Here is what I have come up with so far:

```
Formatters.Where(Function(f As DataModel.Formatter) _
                                                     Formatters.Select(Function(f2 As DataModel.Formatter) f2.Name.ToLower()).Contains(f.Name.ToLower())).Count > 1
```

However the above always returns true as long as their are more then 1 elements in the list, can someone please give me a hand with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here it is in C#. Should be easy to convert to VB.NET, but I don't have a visual studio install handy:

```
    var query = from g in Formatters.GroupBy( f => f.Name, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
                where g.Count () > 1
                select g;

    if (query.Any()){
        Console.WriteLine("Duplicate names!");
    }
```

Comment: I suspect you need a ToLower call in there as well, but otherwise that looks good.

Comment: I changed my code to use the overload of GroupBy that accepts an IEqualityComparer, to avoid the use of ToLower. Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: If you're already using GroupBy explicitly, it's probably worth using Where as an extension method too - it'll end up being simpler code.

Comment: I really like the LINQ syntax any chance I get ;) but you're probably right in this case.